# Подстановка переменной в строку-шаблон регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток!
Пишу систему проверки сгенерированных значений параметров с эталонными. В некоторых случаях приходится сравнивать строки, где меняются индексы.
Например, имеется список строк

```
['aaaaaa-0_bbb0_ccc', 'aaaaaa-0_bbb1_ccc', 'aaaaaa-1_bbb0_ccc', 'aaaaaa-1_bbb1_ccc']
```

Шаблон для проверки по регулярному выражению -

```
r'aaaaaa\-[\d]{1}\_bbb[\d]{1}\_ccc'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется ли возможность как-то в рамках (возможно?) цикла динамически менять шаблон регулярки в части `bbb[\d]{1}` на конкретную часть строки - bbb0, bbb1 и т.д.? хотелось бы получить изменяемый шаблон вида `r'aaaaaa\-[\d]{1}\_bbb[переменная]\_ccc'`, но пока что сам не смог дойти до конкретной идеи.
На выходе ожидаю результат работы функции `re.match(изменяемый_шаблон, строка_из_списка)`

Comment: что вы ожидаете получить на выходе из указанного  списка на входе?

Comment: результат работы функции re.match для каждой строки указанного списка в сравнении с измененным шаблоном. Индекс в подстроке `bbb` зависит от значения одного из входных параметров. Поэтому хотелось бы проверять заодно и его.

Comment: т.е. список с конкретными значениями вы не можете (хотите) привести в ответе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно *одного* шаблона: `(?P<digit>\d+)` вместо нескольких шаблонов с жёстко прописанной цифрой (для этого регулярные выражения и существуют, чтобы не было необходимости буквально совпадения искать). Если хотите напечатать, группируя результаты, по значению `digit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
strings = ['aaaaaa-0_bbb0_ccc', 'aaaaaa-0_bbb1_ccc',
           'aaaaaa-1_bbb0_ccc', 'aaaaaa-1_bbb1_ccc']

results = [[] for _ in range(10)]
for s in strings:
    m = re.fullmatch(r'aaaaaa-\d_bbb(?P<digit>\d)_ccc', s)
    if m:
        results[int(m.groupdict()['digit'])].append(m.string)

for digit, lst in enumerate(results):
    if lst:
        print(f'{digit}:', *lst)
```

Результат:

```
0: aaaaaa-0_bbb0_ccc aaaaaa-1_bbb0_ccc
1: aaaaaa-0_bbb1_ccc aaaaaa-1_bbb1_ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

> имеется ли возможность как-то в рамках (возможно?) цикла динамически менять шаблон регулярки в части bbb[\d]{1} на конкретную часть строки - bbb0, bbb1 и т.д.?

```
import re                                                                       

ss = ['aaaaaa-0_bbb0_ccc', 'aaaaaa-0_bbb1_ccc', 'aaaaaa-1_bbb0_ccc', 'aaaaaa-1_bbb1_ccc']

pref = r'aaaaaa\-[\d]{1}\_bbb'                                                  
suff = r'\_ccc'                                                                 

for k in range(2):                                                              
    pattern = pref + str(k) + suff                                              
    print("matching:", pattern)                                                
    prog = re.compile(pattern)                                                  
    for s in ss:                                                                
        res = prog.match(s)                                                     
        if res: print(res.group())                                              
    print()
```

Output:

```
matching: aaaaaa\-[\d]{1}\_bbb0\_ccc
aaaaaa-0_bbb0_ccc
aaaaaa-1_bbb0_ccc

matching: aaaaaa\-[\d]{1}\_bbb1\_ccc
aaaaaa-0_bbb1_ccc
aaaaaa-1_bbb1_ccc
```

Вообще, наиболее прямой способ делать подобные вещи -- это заранее заготавливать строку-шаблон типа `s = "a{}b"`, а после уже в цикле вызывать `s.format(n)`. Но здесь возник конфликт между синтаксисом `str.format` и синтаксисом `re.match`, поэтому пришлось разбить на суффикс и префикс, и лепить строку из трёх компонент. Возможно, эту проблему можно обойти как-то более правильно, тут я не подскажу.